# Category and tag urls return 404 error

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, tags

My google search console shows that i have some 404 urls espacially with urls like : /tag/example-tag and /category/example-cat

my permalink configuration is as follow :

[image]

anything that could help me, will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have an archive.php set up in your template? Are you using tags and categories, or are these just paths that are dead ends for your site?

Comment: Yes, i have actually the archive.php template, but still get the 404 error page,

Comment: Usually this is a permalink flush issue (eg. save changes in the view you posted, which you've probaly tried). Are your other permalinks working correctly.